# Action Bar for Android being replaced by Menu Button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Not sure if this is the appropriate place for this question, but here goes. I'm following the android tutorial for creating apps and I'm finding some issues with the implementation of the menus in the action bar. (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html). I am testing on my Samsung Galaxy S4.

I am making an App for Android 3.0 and above but when I follow those instructions, the menu doesn't appear in the action bar, but becomes visible only when I press the menu button. If I follow the Android 2.1 and above instructions, the menu buttons appear in the action bar, except the overflow menu which is activated by pressing the menu button.

What do I need to do for Android 3.0 and above to make the menu appear in the action bar? Or is this no longer the way it works and it is meant to appear using the menu button instead now?

Answer (score 0):

In menu.xml use showAsAction="always"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_start"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Start"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_signout"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="logout"/>

</menu>
```